# How can I use a different SSH port on TextWrangler?

Tags: macos, ssh, textwrangler

I want to use a different port number for connecting to a remote server via SSH on TextWrangler on Mac OS X.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most programs you can use various ports for, you simply append `:portnum` to the end of the `ip` or `domain name`.

For example, I used:

```
Server: http://192.168.1.1:2222
```

Works fine for me.